# Open Accept Terms & Consitions Add Delivery Info

Tags: php, opencart

I am trying to add delivery information to the info you have to accept before checking out on OpenCart

The code in the language file is as follows:

```
$_['text_agree']                     = 'I have read and agree to the <a class="colorbox" href="%s" alt="%s"><b>%s</b></a>';
```

I have tryed adding the delivery terms as follows:

```
$_['text_agree']                     = 'I have read and agree to the <a class="colorbox" href="%s" alt="%s"><b>%s</b></a> and <a class="colorbox" href="https://****/delivery-information">Delivery Terms</a>';
```

but the box that opens load the whole page and not just the text like the terms does

any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at `catalog/controller/information/information.php::info()` - this is returning only the information text without rendering the whole page. Your `https://****/delivery-information` should do the same - but only for the colorbox modal window purposes - therefor I think it's better to user URL like `https://****/index.php?route=information/information/info&information_id=<DELIVERY_INFO_ID>` - replace the `<DELIVERY_INFO_ID>` with the correct ID number.

Comment: I added the comment as an answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `catalog/controller/information/information.php::info()` - this is returning only the information text without rendering the whole page. Your `https://****/delivery-information should do the same` - but only for the colorbox modal window purposes.

Therefor I think it's better to user URL like `https://****/index.php?route=information/information/info&information_id=<DELIVERY‌​_INFO_ID>` - replace the `<DELIVERY_INFO_ID>` with the correct ID number.